# ReactJs: Changing state inside an <input> tag

Tags: reactjs

Normally to change a change in a text field I've done something like this:

`<input type="text" onChange={this.handleFirst}/>`

```
handleFirst: function(e){
        this.setState({
            first: e.target.value
        });
    },
```

But I have a few `input` fields and would like to avoid creating multiple handlers to manage a change in state.

Is there a way to do something like this?

`<input type="text" onChange={this.setState({last:e.target.value})}/>`

When I try that, I'm getting an error saying `e is not defined` (which I understand). Is there a way to access the value of `input`?

Comment: You can use input `name` as key - https://jsfiddle.net/b59roefb/

Comment: Im new to react...what does e.target.name refer to?

Comment: is that the right link, I don't see anything?

Comment: Sorry I did not save example - https://jsbin.com/qidapihiya/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Ahh! Ok. Thank you. That works too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, you need to wrap it inside a function:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({ last: e.target.value })} />
```

The onChange event awaits a function to invoke, not a statement.

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote that...it worked